# Determining if two vectors contain two adjacent items the same

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, vector, stl

I have a problem that concerns determining if two vectors contain two elements the same. The elements may be anywhere in the vector, but they must be adjacent.

**EDITED FOR MORE EXAMPLES**

For example the following two vectors, when compared, would return false.

Vector 1 = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6 ]

Vector 2 = [ 1, 4, 2, 0, 5, 3 ]

But the following two would return true:

Vector 1 = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]

Vector 2 = [ 4, 2, 1, 5, 0, 3 ]

because the 1,2 in the first vector would correspond to the 2,1 in the second vector.

True:

Vector 1 = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]

Vector 2 = [ 1, 4, 2, 0, 5, 3 ]

{5,0} is a pair, despite looping around the vector (I originally said this was false, thanks for spotting that 'Vlad from Moscow').

True:

Vector 1 = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]

Vector 2 = [ 4, 8, 6, 2, 1, 5, 0, 3 ]

{2,1} is still a pair, even though they are not in the same position

The actual application is that I have a polygon (face) with N points stored in a vector. To determine if a set of polygons completely enclose a 3D volume, I test each face to ensure that each edge is shared by another face (where an edge is defined by two adjacent points).

Thus, Face contains a vector of pointers to Points...

```
std::vector<Point*> points_;
```

and to check if a Face is surrounded, Face contains a member function...

```
bool isSurrounded(std::vector<Face*> * neighbours)
{
    int count = 0;
    for(auto&& i : *neighbours)     // for each potential face
        if (i != this)              // that is not this face
            for (int j = 0; j < nPoints(); j++) // and for each point in this face
                for (int k = 0; k < i->nPoints(); k++ ) // check if the neighbour has a shared point, and that the next point (backwards or forwards) is also shared
                    if ( ( this->at(j) == i->at(k) )        // Points are the same, check the next and previous point too to make a pair
                       && (    ( this->at((j+1)%nPoints()) == i->at((k+1)%(i->nPoints())) )
                            || ( this->at((j+1)%nPoints()) == i->at((k+i->nPoints()-1)%(i->nPoints())) )))
                        { count++; }
    if (count > nPoints() - 1) // number of egdes = nPoints -1
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Now, obviously this code is horrible. If I come back to this in 2 weeks, I probably won't understand it. So faced with the original problem, how would you neatly check the two vectors?

Note that if you are trying to decipher the provided code. `at(int)` returns the Point in a face and `nPoints()` returns the number of points in a face.

Many thanks.

Comment: Ah - another person who uses the "2 week rule".

Comment: I should specify that the two vectors can be any length.

Comment: Give a few more "no match" and "match" examples (different length, different positions) including corner cases (start/end -- are they a pair?)

Answer (score 1):

Not efficient but following is a possibility.

```
bool comparePair ( pair<int,int> p1, pair<int,int> p2 ) {
  return ( p1.first == p2.first && p1.second == p2.second )
           || ( p1.second == p2.first && p1.first == p2.second );
}

//....

vector< pair<int,int> > s1;
vector< pair<int,int> > s1;
vector< pair<int,int> > intersect( vec1.size() + vec2.size() );

for ( int i = 0; i < vec1.size()-1; i++ ) {
  pair<int, int> newPair;
  newPair.first = vec1[i];
  newPair.first = vec1[i+1];
  s1.push_back( newPair );
}

for ( int i = 0; i < vec2.size()-1; i++ ) {
  pair<int, int> newPair;
  newPair.first = vec2[i];
  newPair.first = vec2[i+1];
  s2.push_back( newPair );
}

auto it = std::set_intersection ( s1.begin(), s1.end(), s2.begin(), s2.end(), 
                                   intersect.begin(), comparePair );

return ( it != intersect.begin() ); // not sure about this.
```

Comment: I like it, its slightly neater than mine as it removes one for loop. But it also assumes vec1 and vec2 are the same size, which I should have specified - is not always the case

Comment: Ah, yes, but that highlights the other problem that the two elements may not be at the same location in the vector. It may be that the first two elements in vec1 match the last two in vec2.

Comment: `std::set_intersection` expects its inputs to be sorted. There is also a trivial typo, I guess `newPair.second = vec1[i+1];` and `newPair.second = vec2[i+1];` are meant.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question:

```
std::vector<int> a, b;
std::vector<int>::iterator itB = b.begin();
std::vector<int>::iterator itA;
std::vector<std::vector<int>::iterator> nears;
std::vector<int>::iterator near;
for(;itB!=b.end() ; ++itB) {
    itA = std::find(a.begin(), a.end(), *itB);
    if(nears.empty()) {
        nears.push_back(itA);
    } else {
     /* there's already one it, check the second */  
      if(*(++nears[0])==*itA && itA != a.end() {
        nears.push_back(itA);
      } else {
        nears.clear();
        itB--;
      }         
    }
    if(nears.size() == 2) {
      return true;
    } 
}
return false;
```

Comment: I see the angle you're coming from, essentially creating temporary storage to track a pair. But you would also have to check `--nears[0]` for the case that the elements form a pair in reverse order (I think?). Its a nice angle to take, but I'm looking for a more succinct solution really.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
class AdjacentSort
{
public:
    AdjacentSort(const vector<int>& ref);
    ~AdjacentSort();

    bool operator()(int e1,int e2) const;
private:
    const vector<int>& ref_;
};

AdjacentSort::AdjacentSort(const vector<int>& ref):
    ref_(ref)
{
}

bool AdjacentSort::operator()(int e1, int e2) const
{
    auto it1 = find(ref_.begin(),ref_.end(),e1);
    auto it2 = find(ref_.begin(),ref_.end(),e2);

    return distance(it1,it2) == 1;
}

AdjacentSort::~AdjacentSort()
{
}

int main()
{
    vector<int> vec {1,2,3,4,5};
    vector<int> vec2 {1,3,5,4,2};

    AdjacentSort func(vec);
    auto it = adjacent_find(vec2.begin(),vec2.end(),func);

    cout << *it << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

It returns the first element where two adjacent numbers are found, else it returns the end iterator.

Comment: This is one of my favourite answers - especially if I could do away with the class and replace func with a lambda function.

Comment: Yes it is possible, but I found it more elegant to do it separately in a functor.

Answer (score 1):

Here is way if your element are same set of elements then assign index for each. (Didnt mention corner cases in pseudo ) :-

```
for(int i=0;i<vect1.size;i++) {

   adj[vect1[i]][0] = vect1[i-1];
   adj[vect2[i]][1] = vect2[i+1];
}

for(int j=0;j<vect2.size();j++) {

    if(arr[vect2[i]][0]==(vect2[j-1] or vect[j+1]))
       return true
    if(arr[vect2[i]][1]==(vect2[j-1] or vect[j+1]))
       return true

}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood correctly these two vectors

```
std::vector<int> v1 = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
std::vector<int> v2 = { 3, 5, 2, 1, 4, 0 };
```

contain adjacent equal elements. They are pair {1, 2 } in the first vector and pair { 2, 1 } in the second vector though positions of the pairs are different in the vectors.

In fact you already named the appropriate standard algorithm that can be used in this task. It is std::adjacent_find. For example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>


int main() 
{
    std::vector<int> v1 = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    std::vector<int> v2 = { 3, 5, 2, 1, 4, 0 };

    bool result =
        std::adjacent_find( v1.begin(), v1.end(),
            [&v2]( int x1, int y1 )
            {
                return std::adjacent_find( v2.begin(), v2.end(),
                [=]( int x2, int y2 ) 
                { 
                    return ( x1 == x2 && y1 == y2 || x1 == y2 && y1 == x2 );
                } ) != v2.end();
            } ) != v1.end();

    std::cout << "result = " << std::boolalpha << result << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think this is an interesting idea. However, the OP's question requires that the vector's last and the first element should be considered as adjacents (this wasn't made very clear). `std::adjacent_if` does'n do that but a few extra lines of code should be enough to test this case and complete your answer.

Comment: @Cassio If what you are saying is indeed correct then these two vectors
Vector 1 = [ 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]

Vector 2 = [ 1, 4, 2, 0, 5, 3 ]
have adjacent equal pair {0, 5}. However in the original post there was said nothing that this pair exists.

Comment: You are both correct, I did mean that the last and first element should be considered adjacent, and I did give a bad example. I have edited my post to reflect this. This is a very interesting answer though, I will have to look deeper at std::adjacent_find().

Answer (score 1):

Here's my attempt at this problem.  Quite simply, iterate through `a`, find the same element in `b` and then compare the next element in `a` with the elements before and after our position in `b`.

If it's a little wordier than it needed to be it was so that this function can be called with any containers.  The only requirement is that the containers' iterators have to bidirectional.

```
    #include <vector>
    #include <iostream>
    #include <algorithm>
    #include <list>

    using namespace std;

    template <class Iter>
    pair<Iter, Iter> get_neighbors(Iter begin, Iter current, Iter end)
    {
        auto p = make_pair(end, next(current));
        if(current != begin)
            p.first = prev(current);
        return p;
    }

    template <class Iter1, class Iter2>
    bool compare_if_valid(Iter1 p1, Iter1 end1, Iter2 p2)
    {
        return p1 != end1 && *p1 == *p2;
    }

    template <class C1, class C2>
    auto neighbors_match(const C1 & a, const C2 & b) ->
        decltype(make_pair(begin(a), begin(b)))
    {
        for(auto i = begin(a); i != end(a) && next(i) != end(a); ++i)
        {
            auto pos_in_b = find(begin(b), end(b), *i);
            if(pos_in_b != end(b))
            {
                auto b_neighbors = get_neighbors(begin(b), pos_in_b, end(b));
                if(compare_if_valid(b_neighbors.first, end(b), next(i)))
                    return {i, b_neighbors.first};
                else if(compare_if_valid(b_neighbors.second, end(b), next(i)))
                    return {i, pos_in_b};
            }
        }
        return {end(a), end(b)};
    }

    int main()
    {
        vector<int> a = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        vector<int> b = {1, 4, 2, 0, 5, 3};
        cout << boolalpha << (neighbors_match(a, b).first != a.end()) << endl;
        vector<int> a2 = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
        list<int> b2 = {4, 2, 1, 5, 0, 3};
        auto match = neighbors_match(a2, b2);
        cout << boolalpha << distance(a2.cbegin(), match.first)
             << ' ' << distance(b2.cbegin(), match.second) << endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: I like how this is suitable for different kinds of containers - but you're right, it does make it very wordy!

Answer (score 1):

What you are essentially asking for is whether the edge sets of two faces (let's call them `a` and `b`) are **disjoint** or not. This can be decomposed into the problem of whether any of the edges in `b` are in `a`, which is just a **membership test**. The issue then, is that vectors are not great at membership tests.

My solution, is to convert one of the vectors into an `unordered_set< pair<int, int> >`.
an `unordered_set` is just a hash table, and the pairs represent the edges.

In representing edges, I've gone for a normalising scheme where the indices of the vertices are in increasing order (so `[2,1]` and `[1,2]` both get stored as `[1,2]` in my edge set). This makes equality testing that little bit easier (in that it is just the equality of the pair)

So here is my solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_set>
using namespace std;

using uint = unsigned int;
using pii = pair<int,int>;

// Simple hashing for pairs of integers
struct pii_hash {
    inline size_t
    operator()(const pii & p) const
    {
        return p.first ^ p.second;
    }
};

// Order pairs of integers so the smallest number is first
pii ord_pii(int x, int y) { return x < y ? pii(x, y) : pii(y, x); }

bool
shares_edge(vector<int> a, vector<int> b)
{
    unordered_set<pii, pii_hash> edge_set {};

    // Create unordered set of pairs (the Edge Set)
    for(uint i = 0; i < a.size() - 1; ++i)
        edge_set.emplace( ord_pii(a[i], a[i+1]) );

    // Check if any edges in B are in the Edge Set of A
    for(uint i = 0; i < b.size() - i; ++i)
    {
        pii edge( ord_pii(b[i], b[i+1]) );

        if( edge_set.find(edge) != edge_set.end() )
            return true;
    }

    return false;
}

int main() {
    vector<int>
        a {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
        b {1, 4, 2, 0, 5, 3},
        c {4, 2, 1, 0, 5, 3};

    shares_edge(a, b); // false
    shares_edge(a, c); // true

    return 0;
}
```

In your particular case, you may want to make `shares_edge` a member function of your `Face` class. It may also be beneficial to precompute the edge set and store it as an instance variable of `Face` as well, but that depends on how often the edge data changes vs how often this calculation occurs.

**EDIT** Extra Solution

**EDIT 2** Fixed for question change: edge set now wraps around point list.

Here's what it would look like if you added the edge set, precomputed at initialisation to some sort of `Face` class. The private nested `Edge` class can be thought of as decorating your current representation of an edge (i.e. two adjacent positions in the point list), with an actual class, so that collections like sets can treat the index into the point list as an actual edge:

```
#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
#include <utility>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_set>

using uint = unsigned int;

class Face {
    struct Edge {
        int  _index;
        const std::vector<int> *_vertList;

        Edge(int index, const std::vector<int> *vertList)
            : _index {index}
            , _vertList {vertList}
        {};

        bool
        operator==(const Edge & other) const
        {
            return
                ( elem() == other.elem() && next() == other.next() ) ||
                ( elem() == other.next() && next() == other.elem() );
        }

        struct hash {
            inline size_t
            operator()(const Edge & e) const
            {
                return e.elem() ^ e.next();
            }
        };

    private:
        inline int elem() const { return _vertList->at(_index); }

        inline int
        next() const
        {
            return _vertList->at( (_index + 1) % _vertList->size() );
        }
    };

    std::vector<int>                     _vertList;
    std::unordered_set<Edge, Edge::hash> _edgeSet;

public:

    Face(std::initializer_list<int> verts)
        : _vertList {verts}
        , _edgeSet {}
    {
        for(uint i = 0; i < _vertList.size(); ++i)
            _edgeSet.emplace( Edge(i, &_vertList) );
    }

    bool
    shares_edge(const Face & that) const
    {
        for(const Edge & e : that._edgeSet)
            if( _edgeSet.find(e) != _edgeSet.end() )
                return true;

        return false;
    }

};

int main() {

    Face
        a {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
        b {1, 4, 2, 0, 5, 3},
        c {4, 2, 1, 0, 5, 3},
        d {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 6},
        e {4, 8, 6, 2, 1, 5, 0, 3};

    assert( !d.shares_edge(b) );
    assert(  a.shares_edge(b) );
    assert(  a.shares_edge(c) );
    assert(  a.shares_edge(e) );

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see, this added abstraction makes for a quite pleasing implementation of `shares_edge()`, but that is because the real trick is in the definition of the `Edge` class (or to be more specific the relationship that `e1 == e2 <=> Edge::hash(e1) == Edge::hash(e2)`).

Comment: This is cool. In my application I create 3D polyhedra from "Faces", which are created from "Points". I could add "Edges" into this system and create member functions for comparing equality which would probably be the neatest solution - but I decided that storing the Points in order would be enough. Thanks for the response!

Comment: You needn't add `Edge`s explicitly. It would be fine for the `Face` class to generate its edgeset at initialisation, whilst still keeping a reference to the ordered list of points (which would, I realise, by useful for actual drawing commands). I've added an extra solution to my answer which adds the edge set to a Face class, in addition to the list of points.

Answer (score 1):

First, write a `make_paired_range_view` which takes a range and returns a range whose iterators return `std::tie( *it, *std::next(it) )`.  `boost` can help here, as their iterator writing code makes this far less annoying.

Next, `unordered_equal` takes two `pair`s and compares them ignoring order (so they are equal if the first both equal and the second both equal, or if the first equals the other second and vice versa).

Now we look for each of the left hand side's pairs in the right hand side using `unordered_equal`.

This has the advantage of taking 0 extra memory, but the disadvantage of O(`n^2`) time.

If we care more about time than memory, we can instead shove the `pair`s above into an `unordered_set` after *sorting* the `pair` to be in a canonical order.  We then to through the second container, testing each pair (after sorting) to see if it is in the `unordered_set`.  This takes `O(n)` extra memory, but runs in `O(n)` time.  It can also be done without fancy dancy vector and range writing.

If the elements are more expensive than `int`, you can write a custom `pseudo_pair` that holds pointers and whose hash and equality is based on the content of the pointers.

Comment: +1 for the pair and unordered_set approach. It ends up being a lot of abstraction for what should be a simple algorithm though.

Answer (score 1):

An interesting "how would you do it..." problem... :-)  It got me to take a 15 minute break from slapping edit boxes and combo boxes on forms and do a bit of programming for a change... LOL

So, here's how I think I'd do it...

First I'd define a concept of an edge as a pair of values (pair of ints - following your original example).  I realize your example is just a simplification and you're actually using vectors of your own classes (Point* rather than int?) but it should be trivial to template-ize this code and use any type you want...

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

typedef pair<int, int> edge;
```

Then I would create a set class that will keep its elements (edges) ordered in the way we need (by comparing edges in the order insensitive manner - i.e. if e1.first==e2.first and e1.second==e2.second then edges e1 and e2 are the same, but they are also same if e1.first==e2.second and e1.second==e2.first).  For this, we could create a functional:

```
struct order_insensitive_pair_less
{
    bool operator() (const edge& e1, const edge& e2) const
    {
        if(min(e1.first,e1.second)<min(e2.first,e2.second)) return true;
        else if(min(e1.first,e1.second)>min(e2.first,e2.second)) return false;
        else return(max(e1.first,e1.second)<max(e2.first,e2.second));
    }
};
```

Finally, our helper class (call it edge_set) would be a simple derivative of a set ordered using the above functional with a couple of convenience methods added - a constructor that populates the set from a vector (or your Face class in practice) and a tester function (bool shares_edge(const vector&v)) that tells us whether or not the set shares an edge with another.  So:

```
struct edge_set : public set<edge, order_insensitive_pair_less>
{
    edge_set(const vector<int>&v);
    bool shares_edge(const vector<int>&v);
};
```

Implemented as:

```
edge_set::edge_set(const std::vector<int>&v) : set<edge, order_insensitive_pair_less>()
{
    if(v.size()<2) return; // assume there must be at least 2 elements in the vector since it is supposed to be a list of edges...
    for (std::vector<int>::const_iterator it = v.begin()+1; it != v.end(); it++)
        insert(edge(*(it-1), *it));
}

bool edge_set::shares_edge(const std::vector<int>& v)
{
    edge_set es(v);
    for(iterator es_it = begin(); es_it != end(); es_it++)
        if(es.count(*es_it))
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

The usage then becomes trivial (and reasonably elegant).  Assuming you have the two vectors you gave as examples in the abstract of your problem in variables v1 and v2, to test whether they share an edge you would just write:

```
if(edge_set(v1).shares_edge(v2))
    // Yup, they share an edge, do something about it...
else
    // Nope, not these two... Do something different...
```

The only assumption about the number of elements in this approach is that each vector will have at least 2 (since you cannot have an "edge" without at least to vertices).  However, even if this is not the case (one of the vectors is empty or has just one element) - this will result in an empty edge_set so you'll just get an answer that they have no shared edges (since one of the sets is empty).  No big deal...  In my opinion, doing it this way would certainly pass the "two week test" since you would have a dedicated class where you could have a couple of comment lines to say what it's doing and the actual comparison is pretty readable (edge_set(v1).shares_edge(v2))...

Comment: A very detailed answer, I appreciate it. If I was calling this from multiple places in my code, I would probably split it up as you have so that I had the simple function call at my disposal. However, as this is something I will only ever do in one subroutine I am trying to avoid over-abstraction and keep it in-line.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is the most concise i can come up with.

```
bool check_for_pairs(std::vector<int> A, std::vector<int> B) {
  auto lastA = A.back();
  for (auto a : A) {
    auto lastB = B.back();
    for (auto b : B) {
      if ((b == a && lastB == lastA) || (b == lastA && lastB == a)) return true;
      lastB = b;
    }
    lastA = a;
  }
  return false;
}
```

Are more time efficient approach would be to use a set

```
bool check_for_pairs2(std::vector<int> A, std::vector<int> B) {
  using pair = std::pair<int,int>;
  std::unordered_set< pair, boost::hash<pair> > lookup;
  auto last = A.back();
  for (auto a : A) {
    lookup.insert(a < last ? std::make_pair(a,last) : std::make_pair(last,a));
    last = a;
  }
  last = B.back();
  for (auto b : B) {
    if (lookup.count(b < last ? std::make_pair(b,last) : std::make_pair(last,b)))
      return true;
    last = b;
  }
  return false;
}
```

If you implement a hash function that hashes (a,b) and (b,a) to the same, you could remove the check for which value is smallest

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a little late with this, but here's my take at it:

Not in-situ:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

template<typename Pair>
class pair_generator {
public:
    explicit pair_generator(std::vector<Pair>& cont)
    : cont_(cont)
    { }

    template<typename T>
    bool operator()(T l, T r) {
        cont_.emplace_back(r, l);
        return true;
    }
private:
    std::vector<Pair>& cont_;
};

template<typename Pair>
struct position_independant_compare {

    explicit position_independant_compare(const Pair& pair)
    : pair_(pair)
    { }

    bool operator()(const Pair & p) const {
        return (p.first == pair_.first && p.second == pair_.second) || (p.first == pair_.second && p.second == pair_.first);
    }
private:
    const Pair& pair_;
};

template<typename T>
using pair_of = std::pair<T, T>;

template<typename T>
std::ostream & operator <<(std::ostream & stream, const pair_of<T>& pair) {
    return stream << '[' << pair.first << ", " << pair.second << ']';
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int>
        v1 {0 ,1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
        v2 {4, 8, 6, 2, 1, 5, 0, 3};

    std::vector<pair_of<int> >
        p1 { },
        p2 { };

    // generate our pairs
    std::sort(v1.begin(), v1.end(), pair_generator<pair_of<int>>{ p1 });
    std::sort(v2.begin(), v2.end(), pair_generator<pair_of<int>>{ p2 });

    // account for the fact that the first and last element are a pair too
    p1.emplace_back(p1.front().first, p1.back().second);
    p2.emplace_back(p2.front().first, p2.back().second);

    std::cout << "pairs for vector 1" << std::endl;
    for(const auto & p : p1) { std::cout << p << std::endl; }

    std::cout << std::endl << "pairs for vector 2" << std::endl;
    for(const auto & p : p2) { std::cout << p << std::endl; }

    std::cout << std::endl << "pairs shared between vector 1 and vector 2" << std::endl;
    for(const auto & p : p1) {
        const auto pos = std::find_if(p2.begin(), p2.end(), position_independant_compare<pair_of<int>>{ p });
        if(pos != p2.end()) {
            std::cout << p << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Example output on [ideone](http://ideone.com/8WYmZB)

In-situ:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <tuple>
#include <vector>

template<typename T>
struct in_situ_pair
: std::iterator<std::forward_iterator_tag, T> {

    using pair = std::pair<T, T>;

    in_situ_pair(std::vector<T>& cont, std::size_t idx)
    : cont_(cont), index_{ idx }
    { }

    pair operator*() const {
        return { cont_[index_], cont_[(index_ + 1) % cont_.size()] };
    }

    in_situ_pair& operator++() {
        ++index_;
        return *this;
    }

    bool operator==(const pair& r) const {
        const pair l = operator*();
        return  (l.first == r.first && l.second == r.second)
                || (l.first == r.second && l.second == r.first);
    }

    bool operator==(const in_situ_pair& o) const {
        return (index_ == o.index_);
    }

    bool operator!=(const in_situ_pair& o) const {
        return !(*this == o);
    }
public:
    friend bool operator==(const pair& l, const in_situ_pair& r) {
        return (r == l);
    }
private:
    std::vector<T>& cont_;
    std::size_t index_;
};

template<typename T>
using pair_of = std::pair<T, T>;

template<typename T>
std::ostream & operator <<(std::ostream & stream, const pair_of<T>& pair) {
    return stream << '[' << pair.first << ", " << pair.second << ']';
}

namespace in_situ {
    template<typename T>
    in_situ_pair<T> begin(std::vector<T>& cont) { return { cont, 0 }; }

    template<typename T>
    in_situ_pair<T> end(std::vector<T>& cont) { return { cont, cont.size() }; }

    template<typename T>
    in_situ_pair<T> at(std::vector<T>& cont, std::size_t i) { return { cont, i }; }
}

int main() {
    std::vector<int>
        v1 {0 ,1, 2, 3, 4, 5},
        v2 {4, 8, 6, 2, 1, 5, 0, 3};

    for(std::size_t i = 0; i < v1.size(); ++i) {
        auto pos = std::find(in_situ::begin(v2), in_situ::end(v2), in_situ::at(v1, i));
        if(pos != in_situ::end(v2)) {
            std::cout << "common: " << *pos << std::endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Example output on [ideone](http://ideone.com/7cPZ0v)

Answer (score 0):

There have been a lot of great answers, and I'm sure people searching for the general problem of looking for adjacent pairs of equal elements in two vectors will find them enlightening. I have decided to answer my own question because I think a neater version of my original attempt is the best answer *for me*.

Since there doesn't seem to be a combination of std algorithms that make the methodology simpler, I believe looping and querying each element to be the most concise and understandable.

Here is the algorithm for the general case:

```
std::vector<int> vec1 = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 };
std::vector<int> vec2 = { 3, 1, 4, 2, 6, 5 };

// Loop over the elements in the first vector, looking for an equal element in the 2nd vector
for(int i = 0; i < vec1.size(); i++) for(int j = 0; j < vec2.size(); j++)
    if ( vec1[i] == vec2[j] &&
        // ... Found equal elements, now check if the next element matches the next or previous element in the other vector
        ( vec1[(i+1) % vec1.size()] == vec2[(j+1) % vec2.size()]
        ||vec1[(i+1) % vec1.size()] == vec2[(j-1+vec2.size()) % vec2.size()] ) )
        return true;
return false;
```

Or in my specific case, where I am actually checking a vector of vectors, and where the elements are no longer ints, but pointers to a class.

(The operator[] of the Face class returns an element of a vector belonging to the face).

```
bool isSurrounded(std::vector<Face*> * neighbours)
{
    // We can check if each edge aligns with an edge in a nearby face,
    // ... if each edge aligns, then the face is surrounded
    // ... an edge is defined by two adjacent points in the points_ vector
    // ... so we check for two consecutive points to be equal...
    int count = 0;
    // for each potential face that is not this face
    for(auto&& i : *neighbours) if (i != this)
        // ... loop over both vectors looking for an equal point
        for (int j = 0; j < nPoints(); j++) for (int k = 0; k < i->nPoints(); k++ )
            if ( (*this)[j] == (*i)[k] &&
                // ... equal points have been found, check if the next or previous points also match
               (  (*this)[(j+1) % nPoints()] == (*i)[(k+1) % i->nPoints()]
               || (*this)[(j+1) % nPoints()] == (*i)[(k-1+i->nPoints()) % i->nPoints()] ) )
               // ... an edge is shared
                { count++; }
    // number of egdes = nPoints -1
    if (count > nPoints() - 1)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```